# Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'data'

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, custom-data-attribute

I have quite the brain scratcher here.

I am trying to add data about a song above an html5 audio tag using jQuery. I figured a way I could do this more automated was to add data-* attributes to the audio tag, however i get the error: "Object # has no method 'data'" when I try to pull them back out with jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <audio controls data-artist="horse">
              <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
              <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              <a href="horse.mp3">horse</a>
        </audio>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('audio').before(function(){
                    artist = $('<div>');
                    artist.html(this.data('artist'));
                    return artist;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to find a reason this does not work, but have not been able to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the DOM object. `.data()` is only available on jQuery objects, so re-wrap your object with the dollar sign function:

```
$(this).data('artist');
```

Or more concisely:

```
$('audio').before(function() {
    return $('<div />', {
        text: $(this).data('artist')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was thinking that .data() would tell  jQuery to look at the DOM object and then get the data tags, but it looks like it pulls them in earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to wrap `this` in jQuery:

```
artist.html( $(this).data('artist') );
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the native HTML5 list (which won't work in IE < 9):

```
artist.html( this.dataset.artist );
```